# How to recursively fetch nested relative style sheets using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I am on a web page, we can get entire html source code by

```
document.querySelector('html')
```

I can also download the necessary styles by iterating over styleSheets Object like

```
for (var sheet= 0; sheet<document.styleSheets.length; sheet++) {
```

But the issue I am facing is they have recursively nested links in them , like

```
url("../fonts/fa-regular.woff2") format("woff2")
```

How can I access them and download them locally so that I can serve from my local using JavaScript?

**I want to download all the css and js dependencies and serve from my server/local
Can it be done? Please guide**

Comment: This: `../fonts/fa-regular.woff2` is a relative path. So prefix it with protocol `https://` sub-domain if there is one `api.` domain `.mainname`, and tld `.com`. Just go to the location of that page and copy that url and prefix it to that path.

Comment: since you made an introduction citing strategies that would applied via js on the client side, do you expect to have a web page that can fully download a whole url (and its assets) and change all the dependencies with relative urls? and in the end serve those contents statically as one single file maybe (using base64 encoding)?

Comment: @DiegoDeVita yes  similar to that. But I cant figure out how would it work using JavaScript. There are tools and extensions may be for so, but using JS code, I am not able to figure it out. Please lead to something if you can

Comment: @zer00ne Yes but then I have to manually go through all lines of codes in JS/CSS files, look for relative paths manually and fetch them. Is not the manual traversal hard ? How do I traverse and what do I look for while traversing? something like 'rule.style.src.indexOf('url')' ? Please correct me if wrong

Comment: @recmach do you plan on ripping different sites on regular basis? There's gotta be an app for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best (and right) solution would be to use Node.js

- make fetch to get html data from the sorce
- create regx to retriev all needed paths. collect all of them into array
- make function to get data from paths and chek, if responce has some path inside (to fonts e.g.), call function again (recursively)
- store data ;)

Best regards!